# SQL/MS Access: Adding a automatically updating field in SQL table with sum of values from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am building a database with MS Access, and I am quite new to Access and SQL language.

I would like to add a field in a table which will automatically update its value based on the sum of values listed from another table.

---

### Example:

There is a **staff** and a **payroll** table, and I would like to add a **total** field to the **staff** table, which is equal to the total amount of salary listed in the **payroll** table for each staff.

With a step-by-step approach, I have managed to build a **query** which do the summation of salary for each staff.

**staff**

```
| id |   name   |
|----|----------|
| A1 | staff A1 |
| A2 | staff A2 |
| B1 | staff B1 |
```

**payroll**

```
| id | month | salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| A1 |  JAN  |  10000 |
| A2 |  JAN  |  15000 |
| A1 |  FEB  |  10000 |
```

**summation**

```
SELECT staff.id, SUM([payroll]![salary]) AS total
FROM payroll 
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.id = payroll.id
GROUP BY staff.id;

| id | total |
|----|-------|
| A1 | 20000 |
| A2 | 15000 |
```

---

Expected result:
**staff**

```
| id |   name   | total |
|----|----------| ----- |
| A1 | staff A1 | 20000 |
| A2 | staff A2 | 15000 |
| B1 | staff B1 |     0 |
```

### Questions:

On MS Access, I tried to add a lookup query to the **total** field in **staff** to automatic update the value, but if only gives me a combo box options for selection.
Any suggestions and solutions for this problem will be appreciated, thanks.

```
SELECT total
FROM summation
WHERE staff.id = summation.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `LEFT JOIN` and `NZ()`:

```
SELECT s.id, NZ(SUM(p.salary)) AS total
FROM staff as s LEFT JOIN
     payroll as p
     ON s.id = p.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

You can also write this using a correlated subquery.  This makes it easier to keep more columns from `staff`:

```
select s.*,
       (select nz(sum(p.salary))
        from payroll as p
        where p.id = s.id
       ) as total
from staff as s;
```

If you have a `total` column in `staff` you can update it using the last approach:

```
update staff
    set total = (select nz(sum(p.salary))
                 from payroll as p
                 where p.id = staff.id
                );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying your last approach to update the 'total' in the 'staff' table. However, when I tried to execute the update query on MS Access, it prompted a window saying "Operation must use an updateable query."
Any idea what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

using your main table from STAFF table might work, like ;

```
SELECT staff.id, SUM([payroll]![salary]) AS total
FROM staff 
INNER JOIN payroll ON staff.id = payroll.id
GROUP BY staff.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works the same as my 'summation' query, but I would like to add the 'total' field to the staff table, such that whenever I update the 'payroll' table, the value of 'total' in the staff will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` means, you're summing two tables with common values which means If `B1` doesn't exist into the `payroll` tables, it also will not appear in the relationship table.

`FULL OUTER JOIN` will help you to query all the data from two tables.

*Maybe this chart will explain what I mean;*

[image]

Maybe you need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN`. So, It has to go like that;

```
SELECT staff.id, SUM([payroll]![salary]) AS total
FROM payroll 
FULL OUTER JOIN staff ON staff.id = payroll.id
GROUP BY staff.id;
```

OUTPUT

```
| id |   name   | total |
|----|----------| ----- |
| A1 | staff A1 | 20000 |
| A2 | staff A2 | 15000 |
| B1 | staff B1 |     0 |
```

***Reference:***
[SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, but I would like to update the 'total' field in the 'staff' table instead of creating a new table. I am willing to try this method if the updating approach fails.